# tokens distribution on retro

Tags: algorithm, math, computer-science, solidity

I have a problem that I don't even know if it can be solved, so I hope one of the Geniuses here will give me the answer of how to do it if it's possible or tell me it's not.

In a program I'm am writing, there are users and tokens.
Users can create tokens, whenever a user creates tokens. A tax of that created token needs to be distributed to all the other users based on their current tokens.
The problem I face is that I can't change the values in real-time. I need to understand how many users have only if someone asks for it
For example, let's say users 1,2,3 created 100 tokens each in that order. Each time there was a tax of 10%

| user | create token | user tokens phase 1 | user tokens phase 2 | user tokens phase 3 | tax tokens |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 90 | 110 | 115.5 | 10 |
| 2 | 100 |  | 90 | 94.5 | 20 |
| 3 | 100 |  |  | 90 | 30 |

In the table above, I distributed the tokens in every stage.
Is there a way to do it without distributing it for every user every time user-created tokens, only when the user requests to know how many tokens they have?

Comment: This question may be related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97808/automatically-tax-transaction-and-distribute-to-all-token-holders

Comment: I tried to understand your example: 1. User-1 creates 100 tokens, keeps 90 and 10 will become tax. There is noone else, so tax is not distributed. 2. User-2 creates 100 tokens, keeps 90 and 10 will become tax. The 20 tax tokens are distributed among the other users, so user-1 gets all tax tokens and will have 110. 3. User-3 creates 100 tokens, keeps 90, 10 will become tax. These 10 tokens will be distributed between user-1 and user-2. User-1 has 110, user-2 has 90, so I think user-1 should get 10*110/200 = 5.5, and user-2 should get 10*90/200 = 4.5, but you gave them 6.5 and 3.5. Why?

Comment: @kol you are right. my bad

Comment: You need to store for every user the exact timestamp and number of created tokens for every token creation event. When a user requests their number of tokens, you have to collect this information, and simulate the tax distribution process, like you did in your table above. To make this more effective, you should store this table, and only extend it every time a user requests their tokens. (I don't know much about Ethereum, so it's possible this is harder than I think.)

Comment: I would also perform a tax distribution (that is, extend the above table) automatically, at regular intervals. This way if you store and only extend the above table, the user will be able to get their token count faster.

Comment: The problem with ethereum contracts is that I cant loop over all the users to create the table I showed. So I can't save every one new distribution when every token is created.
Thanks a lot @kol but I think there is no solution